# One word for an excuse given to make the excuse-giver not look stupid

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that names an excuse made so as to not look stupid?

Here is an example that actually happened:

> A guy walks up to a girl and starts talking to her. After talking for some time, the girl asks the guy to give her a kiss, but the guy refuses. So to this, the girl said, "I just wanted to test you if you are a good guy or a bad one."

Comment: Generally speaking, *excuse* or *rationalization*.

Comment: @danbron Excuse.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. My comment was a suggestion, not a question. Those are two words you can use.

Comment: It's not one word, but I would call such an excuse "face-saving".

Comment: @DougWarren - That sounds good enough for an answer to me.

Comment: She tried to [save her own skin](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/save+skin). skin-saving.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not one word, but I would call such an excuse "**face-saving**", which is defined by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/face-saving?q=face-saver#face-saving__4) as "preserving one’s reputation, credibility, or dignity".

Comment: This is what I have been looking for. Thanks! +1 to all the helpful people.

Answer (score 3):

(Not a one word) **She tried to keep up appearances**.

> Definition: to make things look all right whether they are or not; to ​pretend to be ​happier, less ​poor, etc. than you really are, because you do not ​want ​people to ​know how ​bad ​your ​situation is.
>
> Examples: We must keep up appearances even if it means little sacrifices here and there. Things may be unpleasant, but we will keep up appearances. They were very ​unhappily ​married but ​kept up ​appearances for the ​sake of ​their ​children.

Comment: Single word request!?

Answer (score 2):

Justification. "So to this, the girl justified herself by claiming she was testing him."

Answer (score 2):

How about ***[cop-out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cop-out)***?

> : an excuse for not doing something
>
> : something that avoids dealing with a problem in an appropriate way

So it's an excuse, except more emphasis on avoiding something (like not looking stupid in your example). so I think it fits perfectly.

And perhaps if you were to continue the dialogue in your example, the boy might respond "Don't give me that *cop-out*". And that sounds perfect to me.

Answer (score 2):

> **pretext**
>
> *noun*
>
> A reason given in justification of a course of action that is not the
>   real reason:
>   *the rebels had the perfect **pretext** for making their move*
> <sub>[OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pretext)</sub>

So you could say

> A guy walks up to a girl and starts talking to her. After talking for
>   some time, the girl asks the guy to give her a kiss, but the guy
>   refuses. To this, the girl had the perfect **pretext**, "I just wanted to
>   test you if you are a good guy or a bad one."

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context I suggest

[**"an extemporaneous excuse"**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extemporaneous)

> - composed, performed, or uttered on the spur of the moment

[**"an ad hoc excuse"**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ad%20hoc)

> - made or done without planning because of an immediate need

or [**"a lame excuse"**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lame)

> - lame  (adj) not very convincing or effective

Answer (score 1):

An example using 'face-saving' (as suggested by Doug Warren):

> So to save face, the girl said, "I just wanted to test you if you are
>   a good guy or a bad one."

Answer (score 0):

[Lifesaver](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lifesaver?s=ts) is what comes to mind.

**lifesaver**: a person or thing that saves a person, as from a difficult situation or critical moment (Dictionary.com)

*The lawyer excuse was a [lifesaver](https://books.google.fr/books?id=qXNRBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT42&lpg=PT42&dq=%22excuse+was+a+lifesaver%22&source=bl&ots=tw7Z0gYyng&sig=f94o04ZlmtjRfZNGnqN0ihHZM4g&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMIucfrmYSfyAIVy7YaCh3sgQa3#v=onepage&q=%22excuse%20was%20a%20lifesaver%22&f=false)*

Alternately, [face-saver](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/face-saver) might come close to what ypu're looking for.

**face-saver**: something that saves one's prestige or dignity (Random House Dictionary)